# Aspect not works

Tags: java, aop

I have method whick I want tp process:

```
@ApiLogBefore
public ResponseEntity save(@RequestParam("transactionId") String transactionId) throws JsonProcessingException {
...
}
```

I have annotations for it:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ApiLogBefore {
}
```

It's empty now, but not matters.
I have aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ApiLogAspectProcessor {

@Pointcut("@annotation(ApiLogBefore)")
public void logProcessor() {
}

@Before(value = "logProcessor()")
public void before() {
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
}
```

}

When I run this method, it output nothing (but must, as I understand).

Dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '5.1.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.9.2'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.2'
```

Please tell me, how program to go into before()? What's problem?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed is to mark config with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`